# mysqldump: Got error: 1066: Not unique table/alias: 'temp1' when using LOCK TABLES

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

When I try to dump a whole database using

```
mysqldump -htest.com -uabc -p --column-statistics=0 abc > abc.sql
```

The following error occured.

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1066: Not unique table/alias: 'temp1' when using LOCK TABLES
```

I have no problem in dumping other database in the same host, only this database is having problem.
What is the cause and how I can fix it?

Comment: Does you show **exact** command which causes the problem? Also provide `SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'abc'`.

Answer (score 1):

This is may be you are having `temp1` table with same name but the cases may be different.

Check the value of `lower_case_table_names` parameter in your instance.

Rename the same name table with unique name.

```
select table_schema,table_name
from information_schema.tables 
where lcase(table_name)='temp1';
```

Comment: which records ?

Comment: By running the query, I found the following results:
``` abc | temp1,abc|temp1,abc|temp1, 3 records saying there are three temp1 in abc database, I cannot find the table in abc and cannot drop it. Can I just delete the record in information_schema?

Comment: okay, so you to rename this tables to unique names in schema & if they are unwanted then drop them. The exact name of this tables can extracted using Statment : ```show tables from abc ;```